# Method App\Http\Controllers\homeController::home() does not exist error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel5 .
here is **routes.php** file content :

```
<?php

Route::get('/','homeController@home');
```

and i have **homeController.php** file in **App\Http\Controllers** path that contians :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class homeController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

now when running the project it throws this error **Method App\Http\Controllers\homeController::home() does not exist** .
how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers First letter must be a **capital letter**

Change controller name and controller file name from `homeController.php` to `HomeController.php` and class name from `homeController` to `HomeController`

Comment: now it throws this error : **FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 10:
Cannot redeclare class App\Http\Controllers\HomeController**

Comment: i'm using controllers with first letter not in capital and work fine